# Join table with a view without having a column in common - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, view

So I have a query that first creates a view to find the last monday and the date 4 weeks ago to use it later, and then I use this in my query. But I was wondering if I can join the tables to simplify the query.

```
-- Find the dates
CREATE VIEW dates AS(
SELECT last_monday, 
  last_monday - 28 AS four_weeks_ago
FROM(
  SELECT (current_date - ((6 + CAST(extract(dow FROM current_date) AS int)) % 7)) AS last_monday
  ) A
);

-- Find products that sold > 100 in the weeks
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW Products_100 AS 
SELECT product.ID,
    CASE
        WHEN sales_date BETWEEN (SELECT four_weeks_ago FROM Dates) AND (SELECT four_weeks_ago + 7 FROM Dates) THEN 'Week 1'
        WHEN sales_date BETWEEN (SELECT four_weeks_ago + 7 FROM Dates) AND (SELECT four_weeks_ago + 14 FROM Dates) THEN 'Week 2'
        WHEN sales_date BETWEEN (SELECT four_weeks_ago + 14 FROM Dates) AND (SELECT four_weeks_ago + 21 FROM Dates) THEN 'Week 3'
        ELSE 'Week 4'
  END AS Weeks_Product  
FROM Sales
WHERE sales_date BETWEEN (SELECT four_weeks_ago FROM Dates) AND (SELECT last_monday FROM Dates) 
GROUP BY product.ID, Weeks_Product 
HAVING SUM (total_sales) > 100

**Instead of repeating the info a lot, could I use a join like this?**
-- Find the dates
CREATE VIEW dates AS(
SELECT last_monday, 
  last_monday - 28 AS four_weeks_ago
FROM(
  SELECT (current_date - ((6 + CAST(extract(dow FROM current_date) AS int)) % 7)) AS last_monday
  ) A
);

-- Find products that sold > 100 in the weeks
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW Products_100 AS 
SELECT product.ID,
    CASE
             WHEN sales_date BETWEEN four_weeks_ago AND (four_weeks_ago + 7) THEN 'Week 1'
             WHEN sales_date BETWEEN (four_weeks_ago + 7) AND (four_weeks_ago + 14) THEN 'Week 2'
             WHEN sales_date BETWEEN (four_weeks_ago + 14) AND (four_weeks_ago + 21) THEN 'Week 3'
             ELSE 'Week 4'
  END AS Weeks_Product  
FROM Sales
JOIN Dates ON sales_date BETWEEN four_weeks_ago AND last_monday
WHERE sales_date BETWEEN (SELECT four_weeks_ago FROM Dates) AND (SELECT last_monday FROM Dates) 
GROUP BY product.ID, Weeks_Product 
HAVING SUM (total_sales) > 100
```

Comment: That solution looks like it should work to me. Since there is only one record in the `Dates` "table" the join is not going to be very onerous. However, you are not using CTEs, as mentioned in your title. Do you want it to use CTEs? Also, could you explain the reasons you are using a temporary view?

Comment: I edited the title, thanks! I still don't quite know when to use a CTE or a view, so I'm using what I learned so far

Answer (score 0):

Since the contents of the `dates` view is just two static values, you can do this without using views or CTEs.

It looks like it should be inefficient with the duplicated "last_monday" calculation, but these values are only computed once, so the benefit of combining them with the nested select is negligible.

I wasn't sure what your `product.ID` field was defined as, or if it was a join you hadn't shown, so I just made it `product_id` in order to test it locally.

```
SELECT product_id,
  CASE
    WHEN sales_date BETWEEN four_weeks_ago AND (four_weeks_ago + 7) THEN 'Week 1'
    WHEN sales_date BETWEEN (four_weeks_ago + 7) AND (four_weeks_ago + 14) THEN 'Week 2'
    WHEN sales_date BETWEEN (four_weeks_ago + 14) AND (four_weeks_ago + 21) THEN 'Week 3'
    ELSE 'Week 4'
  END AS weeks_product
FROM
  sales,
  (select (current_date - ((6 + CAST(extract(dow FROM current_date) AS int)) % 7)) as last_monday) lm,
  (select (current_date - ((6 + CAST(extract(dow FROM current_date) AS int)) % 7)) - 28 as four_weeks_ago) fwa
WHERE
  sales_date BETWEEN four_weeks_ago AND last_monday
GROUP BY
  product_id, weeks_product
HAVING
  SUM (total_sales) > 100
```

Ordinarily, I would not create a temporary table or view unless I was writing a complex stored procedure that had multiple steps that needed to be performed. Another reason might be if the dataset is extremely large, and the code executing the query needs a persistent cursor to process all of it.

It is also customary to keep your case consistent. Even though SQL is case insensitive, it is a good practice to keep your table and field names lower case, and your keywords upper case.